# geofence android not work with me

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-geofence

I'm working now with coding project that requires me to use GEOFENCE feature that provided by google map on android, which is in general, give you a notification when you become inside the specific region and this is done by tracking your movement with google map.

Generally, to make this code work you need to identify locations(latitude, longitude)and radious(region).

I tried to implement this code by following one of the resources available on the internet that guide me on how to do it by using Google API.And after I finish writing the code no errors appears but, no notification I receive!

I don't now what's the problem ! is itin the code, with the setting of the phone, or the way that I test the code is not correct.!!!!!!

The link that I took code from is:https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud876-1/lessons/3976758718/concepts/43294700190923

The code is:
mainactivity.java:

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<Status> {



//array list of gepfence location
protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;

protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Button mAddGeofencesButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
    // Empty list for storing geofences.
    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

    // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
    populateGeofenceList();

    // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

public void onResult(Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Geofences Added",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
    } else {
        // Get the status code for the error and log it using a user-friendly message.
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                status.getStatusCode());
    }
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

//هذي البتوون اللي راح تكون في الانترفيس وراح تشغل شغلنا كله اللي سويناه فا لوتلاحظبن فيها استدعائات للفنكشن المهمه والرئيسيه
public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.not_connected), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                // The GeofenceRequest object.
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                // A pending intent that that is reused when calling removeGeofences(). This
                // pending intent is used to generate an intent when a matched geofence
                // transition is observed.
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
    }
}

public void populateGeofenceList() {
    //this fun do:1-read hashmap from constant class
    // 2-create geofence obj and add them to array list
    for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
        //for each entry on hashmap I will abstrct it as "Entry:var and the code will deal with it
        //Entery used to bring lat and long

        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()//انشانا اوبجيكت من الجيوفينس بيلدر واسندناه لل لليست
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                        entry.getValue().latitude,
                        entry.getValue().longitude,
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )

                // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                // removed after this period of time.
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)

                // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                // Create the geofence.
                .build());//بعد ما انشاءت اوبجيكت من الجيوفينس بيلدر واسندت له كل القيم اللي حتاجها لوت لونج راديوس والاكبايريشن راح اسوي لها بيلد يعني راج انشاءها وبعدين راح تتخزن في ام جيوفينس ليست
        //mGeofenceList الحين تحمل كل الاماكن اللي ابي يكون عليها جيوفينس

    }
}

/**
 * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the LocationServices API.
 */
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

///////////////////////////////menu//////////////////
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
///////////////////////////menu////////////////

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Do something with result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}




private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    //انشاءت اوبجيكت من نوع جيوفينس ريكويست
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    //راح اخزن بالاولجيكت  وش التريقر اللي يخلي الجيو فينس او النتوفيكيشن يشتغل :انا حطيته انه لما يدخل منطه الجغرافيه الجيوفينس
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    //خرنت في الاوبجيكت ايش اللوكيشن اللي يسوي عليها مونتير في حال لو دخل الجيوفينس حقها
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    //جسويت بيلد لل اوبجيكت واسندرت في قيمه اللي فوقه ومررتها للجيوفينس ريقويست
    return builder.build();
}



private void test_sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    // Construct a task stack.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    // Define the notification settings.
   // builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
            // to decode the Bitmap.
           // .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                   // R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    builder.setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Issue the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
}
```

2.GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.java

```
package com.example.ranaali.geofence3;



import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    protected static final String TAG = "geofence-transitions-service";
//كونستركتور
    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService() {
        // Use the TAG to name the worker thread.
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }
////هذي عباره عن تهيئه الاايفينت ومعناها الحالات اللي ممكن استقبلها مع الجيوفنس.يعني الحين انا سويت هيكله الايفنت وبعدين راح احدد نوع الايفنت
//اللي راح يتعامل معها الكود... واحنا راح نتعامل مع تو ايفينت لما يدخل الجيو فينس ولما يطلع منه
 //راح اخذ الجيوفينس داتا من الانتيت intentاللي تم تمريرها على السيرفس
    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        //لو حدث مشكله لجلب الجيوفينس ايفنت الكود اللي تحت راح يشتغل عشان يطلع له ايررور مسج
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);

            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.راح نتعامل مع تو ترانزيشن اكزت و انتر لما يدخل الجيو فينس راح يكون له بلوك اوف كود ولما يطلع منه الجيو فينس راح يكون فيه بلوك اوف كود يتعامل معه ايضا
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.

        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            //عباره عن ليست راح تحمل اي مكان راح يكون عنده تريقر يعني مثلا لو انا بالسياره وفيه مكانين دخلت الجيوفينس حقهم راح تتخزن بارري..
            // استخدمت الارري عشان لو صار في تريقر على اكثر من مكان لان احنا راح نتعامل مع اكثر من مكان
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            //
            // ئبعدين راح اخذ ليسته وامررها على الفنكشن اللي تحتي على طول+راح امرر التريقرس وهي اللي راح تكون يا دخول او خروج من الجيوفينس
            //وبعدين النتواتج النهائيه من هالفنكشن راح تخزن في فار من نوع سترينج اسمه geofenceTransitionDetails
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Send notification and log the transition details.هنا الفنكشن المتعلقه بالنتوفكيشن اللي يطلع لليوزر لما يدخل او يطلع
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));
        }
    }

    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            Context context,
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {
        //مررت نوع الترنزيشن لهذا الفاريبل
        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);
         //غرضي من هذي الفنكشن انه اجمع كل الاماكن الي ابي يصير لها جيوفرينس واقوله في حال جاء مثلا مكانين مع بعض في نفس النطاق اجمعهم كلهم لي في ون نوتفيكيشن بدال ماكل واحد له رساله
        //وهذا تم تنفيذه عن طريق اني جمعت كل الليست بصيفه سترنينج
        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);
        //فا راح ارجمع نوع الترانزيشن هل هي اكزت او انترنس ومجموعه الاماكن اللي طلع منها او دخل عليها كصيغه اي دي وهو راح يكون اسم المكان
        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
       // builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                       // R.drawable.ic_launcher))
        builder.setColor(Color.RED)
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////هنا فقط اللي يهمني لو تلاحظين اخذت الفاريبل نوتيفيكشن ديتيلس وخليتها التايتل اللي يطلع للشخص لما تنعرض له التنوفيكيشن مسج//////////////////////
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////هنا فقط اللي يهمني//////////////////////

        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

3.GeofenceErrorMessages.java

```
package com.example.ranaali.geofence3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import com.google.android.gms.location.GeofenceStatusCodes;

public class GeofenceErrorMessages {

private GeofenceErrorMessages() {}

/**
 * Returns the error string for a geofencing error code.
 */
public static String getErrorString(Context context, int errorCode) {
    Resources mResources = context.getResources();
    switch (errorCode) {
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE:
            return "geofence servisce not avilable";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_GEOFENCES:
            return "your app has registerd too many geofencses";
        case GeofenceStatusCodes.GEOFENCE_TOO_MANY_PENDING_INTENTS:
            return "geofence too many pending intents";
        default:
            return "unknown error:the geofence service is not avilable now";
    }
}
 }
```

4.Constants.java

```
package com.example.ranaali.geofence3;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.util.HashMap;

public final class Constants {

private Constants() {
}

public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.gms.location.Geofence";

public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME = PACKAGE_NAME + ".SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME";

public static final String GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".GEOFENCES_ADDED_KEY";

/**
 * Used to set an expiration time for a geofence. After this amount of time Location Services
 * stops tracking the geofence.
 */
public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS = 24;

/**
 * For this sample, geofences expire after twelve hours.
 */
public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS =
        GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_HOURS * 60 * 60 * 1000;
//public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 1609; // 1 mile, 1.6 km
public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 1609; // 1 mile, 1.6 km

/**
 * Map for storing information about airports in the San Francisco bay area.
 */
public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
static {
    // San Francisco International Airport.
    BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("My home", new LatLng(  24.764171, 46.722942));

    // Googleplex.
    BAY_AREA_LANDMARKS.put("aljwadah school", new LatLng( 24.7657308,46.7242295));


}

}
```

5.build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ranaali.geofence3"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
}
```

6.AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />






    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that need to be fixed:

- In your Manifest, you must declare your Service (`GeofenceTransitionsIntentService`). This is why your geofences are not working.
- In your build.gradle file, of these three dependencies, you only need one.

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0`

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0`

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0` <-- Keep this one